# npm Karma Installation error

Tags: node.js, karma-runner

I am getting this error when trying to install Karma:

```
C:\Program Files(x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Microsoft.Cpp.InvalidPlatform.Targets(23,7): error MSB8007: The Platform for project 'bufferutil.vcxproj' is invalid.  Platform='x64'. You may be seeing this message because you are trying to build a project without a solution file, and have specified a non-default Platform that doesn't exist for this project. [C:\Users\waheed.CORP\node_modules\karma\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\ws\build\bufferutil.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files(x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Microsoft.Cpp.InvalidPlatform.Targets(23,7): error MSB8007: The Platform for project 'validation.vcxproj' is invalid.  Platform='x64'. You may be seeing this message because you are trying to build a project without a solution file, and have specified a non-default Platform that doesn't exist for this project. [C:\Users\waheed.CORP\node_modules\karma\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\ws\build\validation.vcxproj]
```

Comment: Seems like the error message is telling you exactly whats wrong. It wants 64-bit, which isnt supported by your project